# Find WPF control by Name

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm after some help finding the best way to refer to controls that have been programmtically built in C#

If I pre include a label in XAML and name it `marketInfo` then in code I can set the `Tag` property with something like

```
marketInfo.Tag = timeNow;
```

However, I'm building controls and assigning each a name using something similar to

```
System.Windows.Controls.Label lbl = new System.Windows.Controls.Label();
lbl.Content = market.name + " - " + DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToLongTimeString();
lbl.HorizontalContentAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
lbl.Height = 40;
lbl.Name = @"_" + "marketInfo" + countMarket;
```

How do I refer to these controls from another method? I've read a few posts which suggest using the `visualtreehelper` but this appears to require looping controls to find a particular control. Is there a way to access a control by name to avoid looping?

eg something similar to

```
//pseudo code
SomeControl("_marketInfo5").Tag = timeNow;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There's at least two ways to do that:

- Use the [`FindName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname?view=netframework-4.8) method of the parent container to find the control (but it'll internally involve looping, like the visualtreehelper)
- Create a dictionary to store a reference for each control you create

  ```
  var controls = new Dictionary<string, FrameworkElement>();
  controls.Add("_marketInfo5", lbl);
  ```

  Then you can do:

  ```
  controls["_marketInfo5"].Tag = timeNow;
  ```

Comment: The dictionary is a much better method than recursing, especially as the controls I need are all children several layers deep. I should have thought of that one. Thank you.

Comment: This was a great tip, it didn't work for me, but it led me to what did work. I had to use `control.Template.FindName("name")` to get the child I needed.

Comment: @Fred In my case it was: `(yourcast)control.FindName("name")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use XamlQuery for finding your controls at run-time.[XamlQuery In CodePlex](https://xamlquerywpf.codeplex.com/)

```
XamlQuery.Search(RegisterGrid, "Label[Name=_marketInfo5]").SetValue(Control.TagProperty, timeNow);
```