# how to get a textbox text property, on having the name in a string

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wpf-controls

I'm new to vb.net and theirs problibly a easy answer. I am trying to get values from all the textboxes in my program. and I am looping through all of my textboxes with the name of the textbox in a string. So how do you get the text with only the name of the element in a string? I am also working on a wpf app.

thank-you much.

Comment: Please provide a code example and you might be further helped

Answer (score 1):

You could instead use this approach to loop through all your textboxes:

```
For Each txtBox As TextBox In MyPanel.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
    Dim txt As String = txtBox.Text
    'Do whatever
Next
```

If you really want to get a control from a string (keep in mind that it is very error-prone) then you should check out [CType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x2877xb.aspx):

```
Dim txtBox As TextBox = CType("TextBox1", TextBox)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really use Name property to find textbox object, this question may help:
[Find WPF control by Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238599/find-wpf-control-by-name)

But to me the case is rare. When you name a user control, you would refer it as a named object.