# Accessing an existing object with a custom name

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a series of textblocks  with formulaic names such as "BlockOne", "BlockTwo", etc that are created in my XAML. I want to access the block names with text, ie:

```
if (output.Contains("206.218.192.186"))
{
    TextBlock + "One".Text = "AI";
}
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the FindName function, which lets you find a control, cast it your type, in this case TextBlock, and access it's Text value from there.

```
(TextBlock)this.FindName("myTextBlock").Text = "AI";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [FindName function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the parent container.

Here are some other posts that may expand on the details:

[Find WPF control by Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238599/find-wpf-control-by-name)

[How can I find WPF controls by name or type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/how-can-i-find-wpf-controls-by-name-or-type)