# MVVM WPF: Change property of item by name from ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Let's say I have 12 rectangles defined in a XAMl page like this:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="C" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="226" Margin="10,10,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="69"/>
<Rectangle x:Name="D" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="226" Margin="78,10,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="69"/>
<Rectangle x:Name="E" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="226" Margin="146,10,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="69"/>
<Rectangle x:Name="F" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="226" Margin="214,10,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="69"/>
<Rectangle x:Name="G" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="226" Margin="281,10,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="69"/>
<Rectangle x:Name="A" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="226" Margin="347,10,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="69"/>
<Rectangle x:Name="B" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="226" Margin="414,10,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="69"/>
<Rectangle x:Name="CSh" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="121" Margin="47,10,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63"/>
<Rectangle x:Name="DSh" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="121" Margin="115,10,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="62"/>
<Rectangle x:Name="FSh" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="121" Margin="249,10,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63"/>
<Rectangle x:Name="GSh" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="121" Margin="317,10,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63"/>
<Rectangle x:Name="ASh" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="121" Margin="385,10,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63"/>
```

How can I change the color of a specific rectangle from **ViewModel** without using **CodeBehind**?

**EXAMPLE**: If I press the key "A" on my keyboard the element in my xaml page named "A" has to be colored with green, if I press "B" on my keyboard the element named "B" on my XAML have to be colored in green and so on.

I already have some basic understanding on how binding works, but I can't find any solution around, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hi, can you post what you have tried? You didn't even try to bind Fill property to anything in your viewmodel.

Comment: @Natxo I didn't post anything related to the binding as I don't really know ho to bind something by the object name..

Comment: If you want to handle a pressed key and use it to find the Rectangle by name, then you must use codebehind. There is nothing wrong with doing so in mvvm.

Comment: Do write a behavior, which is listening for key down and evaluate it. You can then __manage in XAML__ to use or not to use this behavior for a particular element.

Comment: @Rekshino thanks for the replay, can please provide some lines of code as an example as an answer? Many Thanks

Comment: You've already asked the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60435992/wpf-mvvm-how-to-change-item-property-by-item-name)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF MVVM How to change item property by item name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60435992/wpf-mvvm-how-to-change-item-property-by-item-name)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski yes, a moderator, said it was a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238599/find-wpf-control-by-name this one (not MVVM pattern related), and closed my question.

Comment: I have posted an example as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

First u need to add this to ur xaml code

```
<Rectangle x:Name="C" Fill="{Binding Color}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="226" Margin="10,10,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="69"/>
```

next u need to create ViewModel

```
publuc MyViewModel() :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        Brush _color;
        Brush Color{get{return _color;} set{_color = value; OnPropertyChanged("Color")}}

  public MyViewModel()
  {
      Color = Brushes.Green;
  }
}
```

and on the end add in your xaml.cs class of your window

`DataContext = new DERDashboardUserControlViewModel();`

U can add button around your Rectangle and create command that will bind to method in your View Model. Here is link how to do taht [How to bind WPF button to a command in ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422945/how-to-bind-wpf-button-to-a-command-in-viewmodelbase)

Comment: thanks for the replay, but that's gonna change all the rectangles Binded with the property "Color", I need to set just a specific one, let's say, for example, only the rectangle named "x:Name="Dsh", not every rectangles.

Comment: U can create dictionary with key to be x:Name and value to be Brush, when u call your method pass x:Name as parameter and then just change one brush from dictionary

Comment: You shouldn't refer a presentationframework.dll in ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

This is a behavior for `Window`:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

public class ListenKeyBehavior : Behavior<Window>
{
    public Brush KeyBgBrush { get; set; }
    private Brush _originalBgBrush;

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.PreviewKeyDown += AssociatedObject_PreviewKeyDown;
        AssociatedObject.PreviewKeyUp += AssociatedObject_PreviewKeyUp;
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var foundEl = GetChildByName(AssociatedObject, e.Key.ToString().ToLower()) as Shape;
        if (foundEl != null && KeyBgBrush != null && _originalBgBrush==null)
        {
            _originalBgBrush = foundEl.Fill;
            foundEl.Fill = KeyBgBrush;
        }
    }

    private void AssociatedObject_PreviewKeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var foundEl = GetChildByName(AssociatedObject, e.Key.ToString().ToLower()) as Shape;
        if (foundEl != null && _originalBgBrush != null)
        {
            foundEl.Fill = _originalBgBrush;
            _originalBgBrush = null;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.PreviewKeyDown -= AssociatedObject_PreviewKeyDown;
        AssociatedObject.PreviewKeyUp -= AssociatedObject_PreviewKeyUp;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }
    public static object GetChildByName(DependencyObject depObj, string searchedName) 
    {
        if (depObj == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
            if (child is FrameworkElement childFrmWrkEl && childFrmWrkEl.Name.ToLower()==searchedName)
            {
                return child;
            }
            var result = GetChildByName(child, searchedName);
            if (result != null)
            {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Apply this behavior to the `Window`:

```
<Window ..... xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:ListenKeyBehavior KeyBgBrush="Green" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    .....
</Window>
```